# Add a second UIViewController within a single-view application

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode-storyboard

I have a single-view application open. I need to have two storyboard views (UIViewControllers), because one is a Table View, but when one of the Table View elements is selected it brings up another screen with a normal UIViewController. Is there any way of creating a second storyboard view  (UIViewController)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course! Those *templates* Xcode provides are in no way "set-in-stone". When Xcode created your Single-View Template, it just gave you a base for creating something more. You can create additional classes, view controllers, views, and resources (other than what Xcode starts you off with in a few ways).

To add another View Controller to your Storyboard, just drag and drop one from the Object Library:

[image]

It seems like you do not have a basic understanding of using or developing with Xcode. I would recommend reading over *all* of Apple's [documentation on Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/About_Xcode/about.html) before going any further. The [Building A User Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/Edit_User_Interfaces/edit_user_interface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH6-SW1) section may be of particular interest to you.